# GTK# delete initialText when widget is clicked

Tags: user-interface, mono, gtk#

I'm creating a search bar to search through a list. I have an `Gtk.Entry` that the search query would be typed into that has an `intialText` telling the user to type the search query there. How would I go about deleting that text when the user first clicks the widget or would there be a better widget to use?

My code so far:

```
Entry SearchText= new Entry("Search for item");
SearchText.Direction= TextDirection.Ltr;
SearchText.IsEditable= true;
SearchText.Sensitive= true;

ContentArea.PackStart(SearchText, false, false, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in my version of gtk# the text in the entry is initially selected so when the user starts typing it is automatically deleted. If that's not enough for you, you can for example use the `FocusInEvent` to clear the text, optionally re-installing it on `FocusOutEvent` if the user hasn't entered anything.

```
public class FancyEntry : Entry
{
    private string _message;
    public FancyEntry(string message) : base(message)
    {
        _message = message;
        FocusInEvent += OnFocusIn;
        FocusOutEvent += OnFocusOut;
    }

    private void OnFocusIn(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        FocusInEvent -= OnFocusIn;
        this.Text = String.Empty;
    }

    private void OnFocusOut(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
        {
            this.Text = _message;
            FocusInEvent += OnFocusIn;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I was trying to use `Activated` instead of `Focus`.